# How to change style of getChildHtml('order_totals')?

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I'm trying to change the background color (from  light grey to white) of several `<th>` and `<td>` in our new sales order email, below:

[image]

The HTML is being outputted by this method:

```
<tfoot class="order-totals">
    <?= $block->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?>
</tfoot>
```

The template `totals.phtml` contains the logic and HTML but I don't see the inline styles responsible for the background in the above picture.

The path to `totals.phtml` is **/magento/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order**

I see the attributes are being assigned with this method:

```
<th <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getLabelProperties() ?> scope="row">
```

Does anyone know where these inline styles are being injected? Thank you.

Comment: Did you check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html#non-inline-styles?